# Complex regex situation

Tags: regex

I have a results list that looks like this:

```
1lemon_king9mumu (2-1), YearofHell (2-0), kriswithak (2-1)0.44440.75000.4444
2mumu6lemon_king (1-2), MogwaiAC (2-0), Dathanja (2-1)0.66670.62500.5655
3MogwaiAC6Dathanja (2-0), mumu (0-2), Jebnarf (2-1)0.55560.57140.5417
4Jebnarf6YearofHell (2-1), kriswithak (2-0), MogwaiAC (1-2)0.44440.62500.4266
5YearofHell3Jebnarf (1-2), lemon_king (0-2), Mig82 (2-1)0.66670.37500.6012
6Dathanja3MogwaiAC (0-2), Mig82 (2-1), mumu (1-2)0.55560.37500.5417
7Mig823Bye, Dathanja (1-2), YearofHell (1-2)0.33330.42860.3750
8kriswithak0Jebnarf (0-2), lemon_king (1-2)0.83330.20000.6875
```

I want to be able to pull the username of the person AFTER the rank (first number) but it is mashed together with points gained by the player, as well as their first opponent.

For example, the first persons name is "Lemon_king", and his opponents were "Mumu", "YearofHell" and "Kriswithak". The numbers on the right are irrelevant for me, but the major problem I have is that the number of points won by the player is there. Lemon_King wins  9 points for first place. I would normally just get the name by looking for the string between 1 and 9, but players usernames can have a 9 in it as well.

Can anyone think of a good solution to this problem to be able to grab the persons username?

Thanks

Comment: It will be difficult/near impossible to come up with a good non error prone regex for this since the usernames can also contain numbers.  It would be easier to change the text to a JSON object if possible.

Comment: Can usernames have digits in them?

Comment: The better question is, why does your results list look like that to begin with...

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Yes usernames can have digits in them. This is the only way for me to retrieve the results like this. Otherwise, I'd have to use OCR which would introduce more errors. I'd like to use this data if possible.

Comment: @acheong87 is right. The data is rubbish. Don't compound the problem by creating a dependency on this rubbish format

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, bring it to us to help you along. You start it, we help. We don't write it for you.  Show us the actual code that you've tried and then we can help you from there.  Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Answer (score 3):

I think you'd need a list of the usernames to compare against; it doesn't look like the results list is "regular" enough for a regular expression.

For example the line

```
7Mig823Bye, Dathanja
```

Could be "Mig82" 3 points vs "Bye, Dathanja", but it could also be "Mig8", 23 points, "Bye, Dathanja" or "Mig8", 2 points, "3Bye, Dathanja".

Is that correct? Because if it is, you aren't going to get away with a simple solution.

**Edit:** Wilson commented that getting the list of usernames might be an option. In that case, something like the following might work:

```
/^\d+?(username1|username2|username3)\d+?(username1|username2|username3)/
```

It will probably take some fiddling to get right.

Here's a plnkr demonstrating it with the data you provided: http://plnkr.co/edit/nJeGfbfHgvh5zJcTWRXS?p=preview

That said, a regex might not be the right tool for this job.

Comment: I don't think you know what "regular" means in "regular expressions."

Comment: Yes, ideally I'd like to get Rank 7: "Mig72" 3 points, vs BYE

Comment: Getting the usernames of all the players is definitely a possibility, and might be ideal to go with in this scenario and search the usernames against the results list.

Comment: What Jared means is there is no way a regex can know which one of his 3 solutions is the correct one. Unless you can add additional constraits: is the rank always a single digit? can user names *start* with a digit? A list of user names is only useful, by the way, if all of its names are unique "enough" -- i.e., it does not contain all of "smith", "smith1", and "smith11".

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, you want something like

```
 (?x)        # allow whitespace and comments just like
             # any real programming language
 ^           # beginning of line
 (   \d+ )   # starts with one or more digits: CAPTURE 1
 (?= \D  )   # must have a non-digit following
 (   \w+ )   # capture one or more "word" characters: CAPTURE 2
 (   \d  )   # next is a single digit: CAPTURE 3
 (?= \D  )   # must have a non-digit following
 (   \w+ )   # capture one or more "word" characters: CAPTURE 4

 # now add things for the rest of the line if you want
```

Your username should now be in the second capture.  I’ve been a tad more careful than strictly necessary, but if you end up munging this, you may need that.  I’ve alos put all the captures  in case you want to move stuff around or pull more stuff out.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide a bit more information, if you want the thing between the first number and second number:

```
[0-9]+([^0-9])
```

The first group will contain the first username.

Please comment on this (so I check) an edit your question with more detail though.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldnt use regex. It will be a pain to debug it, and you'll never be 100% certain you've covered all the edge cases.

Try doing 'manual' parsing using your language of choice's built in string manipulation functions.

Comment: Oh, regexes are certainly the right approach — but there’s no reason to think you need only use one of them. You probably want to use a bit of auxiliary logic. It isn’t really clear what he wants here, because we don’t have expected output for each given line of input. He hasn’t defined what he means by "username", or even "points".  He seems to think points are only between 1 and 9 though.